# Пример эффекта домино в коде

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, дизайн

В книге есть следующий абзац:

> Полиморфизм иллюстрирует другой вид инкапсуляции. Размещая различные
>   реализации за общим интерфейсом, мы скрываем работающий в их основе
>   механизм от клиентского кода. Это означает, что любые изменения,
>   внесенные за этим интерфейсом, являются прозрачными для более широкой
>   системы. Мы можем добавлять новые классы или менять код в классе, что
>   не приведет к возникновению ошибок. Значение имеет интерфейс, а не
>   механизм, работающий в его основе. Чем более независимы эти механизмы,
>   тем меньше вероятность того, что внесенные изменения или поправки
>   будут иметь "эффект домино" для ваших проектов.

Можете, пожалуйста, привести пример такого кода, который может привести к эффекту домино? Что-то не никак не могу придумать такой пример.

Comment: Напишите код, который сыплет ошибку одну за одной - вот вам и эффект домино.

Comment: Я могу легко написать такой и с использованием полиморфизма.

Comment: Мне интересен эффект домино именно в этом контексте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование интерфейсов выдвигает на первый план идею о том, что разные части вашего кода взаимодействуют друг с другом универсальным способом. Соответственно при проектировании вы выделяете более чистые абстракции.

Например вы пишете сайт с каким-то функционалом для зарегистрированных пользователей, создаёте класс пользователя с полями имэйл и фотка и начинаете везде использовать его, но через некоторое время требования меняются и оказывается, что пользователем может быть программа, работающая по апи. У программы нет имэйла и фотки и часть функционала не работает (например вы шлёте уведомление на имэйл), и вы начинаете писать какие-нибудь if'ы и наверняка что-нибудь пропустите. Но если вы разрабатываете интерфейс пользователя, то вы смещаете фокус с того чем пользователь является на то, что пользователь может делать и получаете более универсальные и гибкие абстракции.

Обратите внимание, что автор говорит именно о независимости интерфейса и использующего его кода. Сам по себе интерфейс не панацея от проблем, но независимость разных частей кода -- это то, что делает ваш код гибким и более надёжным.

Особенно полезны интерфейсы в библиотеках. Например вы написали клёвый клиент для апи вконтакте, но для отправки запросов используете `file_get_contents`. Но у пользователя вашей библиотеки может быть резон отключить директиву `allow_url_fopen` тогда он не сможет ей воспользоваться. Однако, если описать интефейс http-клиента, то у пользователя появится возможность заменить стандартную реализацию с `file_get_contents` на свою собственную с `curl` и библиотека будет работать!

Вот ещё бывает.
Новички часто пишут кучу sql-запросов там, где им понадобятся данные из базы данных. В итоге из таблицы `users` (например) данные выбираются в 10 разных местах кода. Наступает день, когда принимается решение внести изменение в схему базы и удалить или добавить некоторые поля в таблицу `users`. Правки в запросы вносятся, но иногда что-то да забывают. Теперь в какой-то части системы может оказаться пользователь без какого-то поля. Если это поле используется в какой-нибудь условной ветке кода, то такой баг может незаметно существовать очень долго и аффектить другие части приложения. Скажем новое поле было уровнем доверия к пользователю, на основе которого принималось решение о необходимости премодерации его комментариев. Теперь там случайно оказался null, если пользователь комментит собственный пост.